# is there a simpler way to update a Mongodb collection in just one line (in command line)?

Tags: command-line, mongodb

right now, i do this in command  line:

```
var obj = db.mycollect.find({id="231412"});
obj.abc = 'new value';
obj.save();
```

3 lines of code..

is there a simpler way to do this?

```
e.g. db.mycollect.find({id=12345}).save({abc:'new value'});
```

Comment: is `id` a string or an integer? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.mycollect.update({id=12345}, {"$set": {abc:'new value'}});
```

This is not only one line but also *atomic*. With your solution if somebody updates the document after you've read it but before storing it that modification will be lost.

Comment: Do you know how to do it in mongoosejs?